# Is there a Query-Mapper like iBATIS.NET but with dirty tracking, lazy-loading and cascading updates?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, stored-procedures, orm, ibatis.net

The problem:

1. A DBA-controlled database with a Stored Procedure-only mandate.
2. An expectation that the domain be defined in POCO's.

So I decided that I need an ORM designed for stored procedures and/or legacy databases.

Ideally the ORM should allow me to declaratively (or fluently) map domain objects to CRUD stored procedures.

Some findings thus far:

1. **NHibernate** would work if only I could control the queries that are generated for lazy-loading.
2. **iBATIS.NET** would work perfectly, but I can't find any examples of:

   1. object state tracking (new/updated/deleted/etc)
   2. parent/child commit transactions (if a parent is updated, update all dirty child objects as well).
3. An **In-House** developed ORM that works with our database conventions is an option and we have already started with this. But I want to make sure we don't have any other choice.

Non-Options:

1. **SubSonic** does wrap stored procs, but it doesn't *map* between procs and entities. I could implement a mapper of some sort if it came to it, but there are other factors also weighting against SubSonic, such as lacking VS2005 (or SharpDevelop) support and mingling data-access with domain objects.
2. **Dropping the SProcs** is not an option. Data integrity is a HUGE concern for the DBA's and the higher-ups and they feel safest with SProcs. It's not my place to convince them otherwise.

Does anyone know of an ORM that suits my needs, **or a way to overcome the limitations in an ORM that doesn't suit my needs 100%**?

*Any* suggestions welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure if "dirty tracking" or "cascading updates" are good descriptive terms of the features I'm talking about... I've never had to communicate this problem so I have no idea what the correct terminology is.

Comment: Personally, I would drop the dba and let him do something more useful than writing sprocs

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to enforcing a stored-proc-only rule, but to be fair: I see benefits in mapping domain objects to queries instead of tables. So even if we did get rid of the stored procs I'd still like to know what my options are.

Comment: How about your DBA writing views instead of sprocs? You can easily map views with NHibernate, and the DBA keeps his layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think NHibernate is your best bet.

You can use loader, sql-insert, sql-delete, sql-update elements to configure store procs for entities and lazy load collections, although it means quite a lot of keystrokes.